# A web service to call a web service

Tags: web-services

Can a web service be so designed, that it inturns calls another web service? (Till date i dont know if we can do this!)
If yes, then can I have an infinite looping of web services calling each other alternatively?

Comment: yes you can. You need to build a "B" webservice client and call from your "A" webservice, and so on. But infinite loops is not a good idea, the transport protocol used to be HTTP, so the natural way is request/response in no long time requiring terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a web service be so designed, that it inturns calls another web
>   service?

Yes

> If yes, then can I have an infinite looping of web services calling
>   each other alternatively?

You can't have an infinite anything in computers (unless it's computer science!)

Most likely your web servers would eventually start reaching their maximum # of connections limit, or the requests would start timing out from the first one on.